# Citation call-outs appears as numbers between square brackets

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

This is my very first post and I'm hoping that this won't break any rule. I've done previous research with nothing similar found on forum.

I'm currently working with natbib, BibTex and a .bst file obtained from de Geological Society of America. 
[The .bst file can be obtained here.](http://geo.distortions.net/2011/02/geological-society-of-america.html)

The style is pretty fine for my purposes, but I keep obtaining this:

[image]

Instead of getting something like **(Ducea et al., 2004)**.

The command `\citep` would be generating the proper citation call-out, as the gsa.bst file says:

[image]

Also, the references appear in the bibliography with the hateful square brackets, and I have no clue from where delete them (don't mind the wrong number, just for illustrate purposes):

[image: e]

Also, I've noticed that my .blg file contains some errors:

***This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: reftex.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file reftex.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file reftex.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file reftex.aux (There were 3 error messages)***

I'm not sure where the reftex.aux file came from, but it contains the following:

***\relax
\catcode `"\active 
\catcode`<\active 
\catcode `>\active 
\@nameuse{es@quoting}
\babel@aux{spanish}{}***

Aaaand my .bbl file is, well, **empty**.

I think that I correctly declared the natbib package and the reference style:

[image]
[image]

I'm stuck at this point. I've tried of running pdflatex>Bibtex>pdflatex>pdflatex in order to make BibTex work well, with no luck. Any help will be so welcomed!

Comment: bibliography styles may use numbered of author names keys for citation, if a publisher provided style for a journal is immplementing numbered bibliography then that is presumably what they want and not normally an author option to change (changing it would simply be a matter of choosing a different bibliography style rather than the one you link to

Comment: Well, understood. Maybe I can live with that. But anyway, the root problem is that reference is not proper displayed at the text. It must be appear as showed upwards.

Comment: Try without option `numbers` for `natbib` ...

Answer (score 1):

The `natbib` package helps manage the "look" of citation call-outs, assuming a bibliography style is used that is compatible with the `natbib` package.

Fortunately, the [JCKS](http://www.peertrack.net/JCKS/Jcks.bst) bibliography style is fully compatible with `natbib`, as may be verified by the following passage, which starts at about line 20 of the style file:

```
 % This bibliography style file is intended for texts in ENGLISH
 % This is an author-year citation style bibliography. As such, it is
 % non-standard LaTeX, and requires a special package file to function properly.
 % Such a package is    natbib.sty   by Patrick W. Daly
```

All you need to do, then, is change the instruction

```
\usepackage[square,numbers,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

to

```
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
```

and re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

You can probably guess by now that "numbers" means "numeric-style citation call-outs and that "square" means "surround the numbers by square brackets". Conversely, "authoryear" means "authoryear-style citation call-outs" and that "round" means "use round parentheses in the outputs of `\citet` and `\citep`.

---

About the other error messages you report (errors in `reftex.blg`, empty `reftex.bbl`): Are you running BibTeX on the appropriate file? Assuming your main tex file is called `myfile.tex` and that that the bibliography file is called `reftex.bib`, you should be running `bibtex myfile`, *not* `bibtex reftex`.

Comment: Thanks Mico. Seen that way the error was more than obvious. Extreme facepalm here.

And nope, I was running LaTeX>BibTeX>LaTeX>LaTeX on my main .tex file. Quite strange, as now my references is working like a charm but the .bbl file keeps empty.

I owe you a lot. Please don't freeze me on carbonite.

Comment: @Hermes - I love the Star Wars reference! OK, I'll won't freeze you in carbonite, but I might throw you into the Pit of Rancor... :-)

Comment: Deal!

Just realized that I have two .bbl files. My info was in Thesis.bbl and not in reftex.bbl. Spoiling is the way to learn.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking Mico, but you are now like a Latex guru. I don't know if is proper to ask here, but, how can I change the “AND” between authors' names in citations in this gsa.bst file? I've tried to change the citation conjuntion "and" for "y" on line 221 in the gsa.bst file (renaming de new file obtained), but I obtain and error here. Sorry for maybe asking in a wrong place.

Comment: @Hermes - Changing the contents of the `bbl.and` function from `and` to `y` should indeed be the way to go. Which error message(s) do you get? (After you created the modified bst file, you did change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` and rerun latex-bibtex-latex-latex, right?)

Comment: Hi again. No message error, just a [?] in the place where the reference must be. You mean replacing all the "and" between authors in bbl file? 
And yes, argument changed and then runned the secuence. All other references works well.

Thanks!

Comment: @Hermes - Something must have gone wrong when you edited the bst file. (Do you know how to perform a diff on the original bst file and your modified copy?) All I can suggest for now is that you start over: find the original bst file, change `"and"` to `"y"` in the function `bbl.and`, save the bst file under a new name, use the new name in the argument of `\bibliographystyle`, and perform the entire recompile sequence (latex-bibtex-latex-latex) once more.

Comment: Done!
After few tries it finally works well!
Thanks a lot Mico!